# gerrit code review tool site initialization error during initial start

Tags: git, gerrit

I am trying to install gerrit code review tool on my local machine using the google documentation provided with all the steps.

Firstly, I am using a Windows system.

things I have achieved in this process:

Install MySQL and created the user and database for the gerrit -- done
Site initialization using java init command - done successfully no errors
created git repos locally and its path is provided during the site initialization.

All this steps give us gerrit.sh file to run

I am using a terminal to execute to the .sh file and  I am getting the following error:

GIT not found.

I looked into the code and found that if git directory is  not found it throws this error. 
So went to the gerrit.config file and provided absolute path to the git repos

Still getting the same error.

Any help with this is highly appreciated as I am stuck on the last step which is starting the tool.

The steps I followed are found here

http://gerrit-review.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my issue. I was using a 3rd party terminal to run the gerrit site which somehow was not able to locate git repos. Then I used GIT BASH terminal and surprisingly it worked without even me making changes to gerrit.config file.